# Search python list with stars?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, wildcard

I am  trying to find a way  to search items in list with stars (`***`) which replace missing letter. I want to allow user to search for medications in list like this (`a*u*g*t*n*`) so that he can get in list (augmentin susp ) and all possible medications containing these search letters.

If user forgets any letter he can replace it with stars in search entry to display all possible items in list containing these letters. Here is my simple code.

I tried to use `re` but i failed and can't use it in a proper way.

User can write in search entry for example (`a*u*g*m*n*`) and press enter, then list will show every possible item containing these 4 letters.

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as TKFont
import customtkinter
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import Image , ImageTk
 
 
root = customtkinter.CTk()
root.geometry('1000x500')
 
def update(data):
    my_list.delete(0 , END)
    for item in data:        
       my_list.insert(END, item)
 
def check(event):
    typed = search_entry.get()
    if typed == '':
        data = medications
    else:
        data = []
        for item in medications:
            if typed.lower() in item.lower():
                data.append(item)
    update(data)
 
my_list=Listbox(root , bg='#2C2C2C' , fg='white')
my_list.place(relx=.1 , rely=.02)
 
search_entry=customtkinter.CTkEntry(root)
search_entry.place(relx=.3 , rely=.02)
search_entry.bind('<Return>',check)

medications=['augmentin Susp' , 'Curam Susp' , 'Megamox Susp' , 'Hibiotic Susp' , 'Clavimox Susp' ,'E-Mox Clav Susp' , 'Averobios Susp', 'DeltaClav Susp' ,"Delatrol tab"] 
 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When you say that the list would show every possible item containing the letter, did you infact mean containing the letters in the exact sequence or an `any` letter among the letters listed? i.e. starts with `a`, once it encounters `a * u`, it needs that `a*u` as the prefix

Comment: and should each `*` match just a single char or any number of chars?

Comment: i mean containing the letters in the exact sequence , and(*) may not match single char , i mean user may write more than one (*) between each letter not only one !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`fnmatch.fnmatch()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.fnmatch) which *provides support for Unix shell-style wildcards* matching:

```py
from fnmatch import fnmatch
...

def check(event):
    typed = search_entry.get()
    if typed == '':
        data = medications
    else:
        data = []
        for item in medications:
            if fnmatch(item, typed):
                data.append(item)
    update(data)
```